# AngularJS directive and string interpolation

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-directive, string-interpolation

**Context:**

I'm applying a Lightbox effect on some DOM elements using an AngularJS directive named `opensAsPopup`.

**Issue:**

Some of these elements have dynamical content coming from a `ng-repeat` directive, and it seems that my `opensAsPopup` directive applies *before* the string interpolation.

Would that be possible to apply the lightbox effect *after* the string interpolation?

---

**HTML:**

```html
<li>
  <a href="/path/to/{{entry.id}}" opens-as-popup>Link</a>
</li>
```

**Script:**

```coffeescript
app.directive("opensAsPopup", [ ->
  restrict: "A"
  scope: {}
  replace: false
  transclude: false
  compile: (tElement, tAttrs) ->
    new lightbox(tElement.get(0))
])
```

Comment: You could use AngularJS $watch and setting a timeout function. Have a reference here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it in the linking function. Scope is not applied till the link phase (which comes after the compile phase). Also do not create an isolated scope on the same element (removed `scope: {}`) as that would mean that you would need to set `scope.entry.id` within your link function. So:

```
app.directive("opensAsPopup", [ ->
  restrict: "A"
  replace: false
  transclude: false
  link: (scope,tElement, tAttrs) ->
    new lightbox(tElement.get(0))
])
```